# Integrating proxy.conf.json of angular in springboot

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I have integrated angular application with spring boot by building it placing it in static folder
My angular application is calling one api which is in external server and is not present in local spring boot server. However, I am getting cross origin error by calling that api and proxy.conf.json of angular does not works in spring boot.I want proxy.conf.json to work in sprinboot application. Can anyone tell me how to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create proxy.conf.json file in the angular project

https://itnext.io/angular-cli-proxy-configuration-4311acec9d6f

this link will help you

**OR**

You can add   `@crossorigin(origin = * )`   this annotation in your spring-boot application to overcome this issue.